# rsync makes 2 backups if cron runs while file is being written

Tags: cron, rsync, backup

I have a crontab to run this `rsync` command every 30m

```
rsync -rtbpgoi --suffix="."$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M") --exclude=".*" \
--exclude="~*" --exclude="[Tt][Hh][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ss].[Dd][Bb]" \
--exclude="[Dd][Ee][Ss][Kk][Tt][Oo][Pp].[Ii][Nn][Ii]" \
--info=STATS0,FLIST0,NAME1 /mnt/datastore/ /mnt/dsbackup
```

What happens is if a file is in the process of being written, such as a long download for example, I end up with an extra backup copy of the file one being a backup of the incomplete download.

Is there some way to make `rsync` ignore files that are still being written to or some other way to avoid backing up incomplete files? I know I can remove the `-b` and `--suffix` switches but I do want to keep the functionality of having it keep a version history when files change.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question**: `rsync`, to my knowledge, does **not** have any built-in way to know that some separate program that you're running (web browser, etc) is actively modifying a file.

Given your type of backup (running over the same source and destination every 30 minutes), you can achieve *eventual* removal of any intermediate files which have different names than the final file (for example, `download_1.zip.tmp` might be an intermediate file for `download_1.zip`) by adding the `--delete` option to the command.

During the first run of `rsync`, the `download_1.zip.tmp` file would be copied to your backup location. Assuming that the download finishes within 30 minutes, the intermediate file `download_1.zip.tmp` would be renamed to `download_1.zip`. Upon the *next* run of `rsync`, `rsync` would no longer find the intermediate file `download_1.zip.tmp` (because it's been renamed to `download_1.zip`) and it would remove `download_1.zip.tmp` and replace it with `download_1.zip` in the backup. This would *also* remove any other files from your backup (`/mnt/dsbackup`) which no longer exist in the source (`/mnt/datastore`).

From `rsync`'s man page (version 3.1.0):

> This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side (ones that aren’t on the sending side), but only for the directories that are being synchronized.  You must have asked rsync to send the whole directory (e.g. "dir" or "dir/") without using a wildcard  for the directory’s contents (e.g. "dir/*") since the wildcard is expanded by the shell and rsync thus gets a request to transfer individual files, not the files’ parent directory.  Files that are excluded from  the  transfer  are  also  excluded  from  being deleted  unless  you use the --delete-excluded option or mark the rules as only matching on the sending side (see the include/exclude modifiers in the FILTER RULES section).